# How can I get the column names of all entities in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, metadata

Like this I can get the column names of my Entity "fields":

```
$entity_columns = $this->em->getClassMetadata('App\\Entity\\Fields')->getColumnNames();
```

Is there a fast way to get the columns of all entities at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any built-in way to do this, but perhaps you could do something like this:

```
$declared = get_declared_classes();
foreach ( $declared as $class ) {
    if ( preg_match( "/App\\\Entity/", $class) ){
        $entityData = $this->manager->getClassMetadata( $class );
    }
}
```